# DataGrid Values not updating after the Edit/Update function

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, .net-3.5

I am using the following code to update the data in my datagrid.

But when I click update the value is updated in the database but it still shows old value in datagrid.

If I refresh the page after that then datagrid shows the updated value.

What could be wrong?

**Code On Update Command:**

```
protected void MySQLDataGrid2_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
      string newData;

      TextBox aTextBox;
      aTextBox = (TextBox)(e.Item.Cells[0].Controls[0]);
      newData = aTextBox.Text;

      decimal comm = Convert.ToDecimal(newData);

      string UpdateHiveCommission = "Update tbl_HiveCommission set Commission = '" + Convert.ToDecimal(newData) + "'";
      MySqlConnection objMyCon3 = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
      objMyCon3.Open();
      MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(UpdateHiveCommission, objMyCon3);
      cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
      objMyCon3.Close();

      MySQLDataGrid2.EditItemIndex = -1;
      MySQLDataGrid2.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call your load mechanism again - since the datasource of your grid isn't updated so it will hold the old data from your last select.
If you have performance issues loading the data again, you could manually alter the data of the edited row.

Comment: how can I manually alter data of the edited row? can you please give a small example on how that can be done?

Comment: just don't call databind - this causes your currently entered data to be replaced with the one in the datasource.

Comment: you could - after the databind just write aTextBox.Text = newData;

Comment: Nope this doesnt work. Writing `aTextBox.Text = newData;` after databind didnt make any difference to the way it behaves.

Comment: then just don't call DataBind(); Otherwise you would need to create a LoadValues() method and call that after the DataBind();

Comment: Or before the DataBind use your open Connection to call your select-statement again - and then the databind - so you would update your values - select them again and bind the new ones to the grid - that should solve it

Comment: If I dont call DataBind method then the textbox in gridview cells dont go away and also the data is not updated in datagrid.

Comment: Ok so does that mean that I will have to reload whole datagrid contents?

Comment: yes exactly - I for myself always write a LoadValues() method in which I check what is visible/should be loaded and simple call that one from Page_Load or from update/delete/insert methods so I don't have to worry about not seeing the currently made updates

Answer (score 2):

quick fix:

You can try to move this line to Page_Load()

```
MySQLDataGrid2.DataBind();
```

Or, after executing the update command, "Refresh" the page by:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Comment: Ok but what happens then when the page is loaded for the first time? it would try to bind nothing?

Comment: This did not work. Infact my whole datagrid becomes empty when I click edit.

Comment: Your DataGrid should be bound to something I suppose, when the page loads for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

After Successful Edit.

Try to call your Databind Method.

something like:

```
private void BindMEthod()
{

//Your code in binding data to your datagridview.

}

        protected void MySQLDataGrid2_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e) {     
      string newData;  
          TextBox aTextBox;   
        aTextBox = (TextBox)(e.Item.Cells[0].Controls[0]);     
      newData = aTextBox.Text;       
     decimal comm = Convert.ToDecimal(newData);  
          string UpdateHiveCommission = "Update tbl_HiveCommission set Commission = '" + Convert.ToDecimal(newData) + "'";    
       MySqlConnection objMyCon3 = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);   
        objMyCon3.Open();     
      MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(UpdateHiveCommission, objMyCon3);   
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();     
      objMyCon3.Close();    
       // MySQLDataGrid2.EditItemIndex = -1;       --
   // MySQLDataGrid2.DataBind(); 

       //Replace with this

    BindMEthod();

    }
```

Hope this help.

Regards

Comment: Thanks :) but may be you didnt notice that I ahve already accepted an answer to this question. Anyways Thanks for the help :)

Comment: :) yeah, i thought you do not have any answer yet..but still your welcome.